# Type comparison with String

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is this possible or is there an easy way to solve this ?

I would like to compare a string value with a type. I have a type like below and a string value incoming from api request.

```
type stringTypes = 'abc' | 'asd'

const testVal = 'testVal'

if (testVal !== stringTypes) {
  // throw error
}
```

I have solved like below but I wondered if there' s another options.

```
type stringTypes = 'abc' | 'asd'

const testVal = 'testVal'

const controlArr: stringTypes[] = ['asd', 'abc']

if (!controlArr.includes(testVal)) {
  // throw error
}
```

EDIT1: I can use Enums but in typescript enums are not extendable. In my case, I need to extend the types according to the db model as shown below. So I need to do comparison with string and a type.

```
type stringTypes = 'abc' | 'asd'
type channelTypes = stringTypes | 'foo' | 'bar'
type streamTypes = stringTypes | 'das' | 'xyz'

const testVal = 'testVal'

if (testVal !== stringTypes) {
  // throw error
}
```

Comment: `stringTypes` is a _type_, it's erased by the compiler in transpilation to JavaScript so doesn't exist at runtime. You need the array of _values_ for runtime checking. To reduce duplication you could derive `stringTypes` _from_ `controlArr`: https://tsplay.dev/WGR0Xm

Comment: @jonrsharpe I couldnt follow, so in my case how to compare `testVal` with `stringTypes`. Thank you for answer btw.

Comment: You can't: again, you need the array of _values_ for runtime checking (because the values, unlike the types, _aren't_ erased).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is just a compiler, so you can't iterate thought a type,
but you could achieve what you want by using `enum` type

```
const testVal = 'testVal'

enum stringTypes {
  'Abc' = 'abc',
  'Dsd' = 'asd',
}

//Check if string is enum value
const isEnumValue = (value: string, enumType: any) => {
  return Object.values(enumType).includes(value)
}

console.log(isEnumValue('abc', stringTypes)) //true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can add them as enums but further I use `stringTypes` as base type and extend it according to db models. Enums are not extendable. I will edit my question.